# Atomic vectors in R and applying function to them

Tags: r

So I have a data set that I'm using from UC Irvine's website("Wine Quality" dataset) and I want to take a look at a plot of the residuals of the data set. The reason I'm doing this is to look to see if there is a an increase in variance so I could run a log based regression. To look at the residuals I apply this code:

```
residuals(white.wine)
```

`white.wine` is how I named my dataframe. However I get this error thrown at me, `"NULL"`. If I want to look at the residuals of a specific predictor variable like `Fixed Acidity` I get this error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Any way around this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Residuals apply to models, not data. You want to create a model of your data, then take the residuals of the model

Comment: @Hugh Yep! Oh yeah I know that I need to create a model first. I just wanted to know what do once I create that model. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hugh was right in saying that "residuals" must be used against a model, but I think your question was also asking about how to apply something over a data frame. In case you just want the variance of each predictor variable, you might want something like:

```
apply(white.wine, 2, var)
```

As the `?apply` documentation says, you need to provide the data, the *margin*, and the function. The margin refers to applying over rows or columns, with 1 signaling to apply a function over the rows, and 2 indicating that the function should be applied over columns. I'm assuming you have predictor variables in columns, so I used a 2 in the code above.

Comment: 1) You have `var` and `white.wine` round the wrong way. 2) `lapply` `sapply` or even `vapply` is preferable when working on columns in a `data.frame`

Comment: good catch, edited. Sorry about that! I just used ```apply``` on a test dataframe with no issues. What have you found to be the advantages of ```[s/l/v]apply```?

Comment: Perfect! I'm actually going to run both regression models and then a clustering model. Just wanted to see what needed to happen once looked at the plot of the regression model. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Nancy apply() will convert a data.frame to a matrix which can have undesirable side effects in the way of type conversion since matrices can only hold one data type at a time.

Comment: @MrFlick9 I see. That's good to remember. Luckily this case is already all numeric (ostensibly) so OP has a working solution. Thanks for clarifying!